# How to call package procedures and functions from GeneXus

Tags: java, oracle, genexus

From a Genexus webapp I must invoke functions in the Packages section of an Oracle DB 11g

In Genexus:

I defined the functions as methods of an external object (EO)

I declared the list of these methods in List of external stored procedures of the Oracle Data Store

I invoke the methods through variables of data type EO

```
&EO.method (&parm1, ...)
```

The application specifies, generates and compiles without errors. But running executes the error: ORA-06550 the identifier 'method' must be declared

What else may be missing? Does anyone know any link of Genexus documentation that explains the procedure to be followed to invoke functions or SPs in an Oracle DB?

Any way of doing this?

Comment: I've never heard of GeneXus, but is "method" the name of a procedure visible to the account you are connecting to?

Comment: Is `method`, mentioned in the ORA_06550 message, defined in the database? Remember, Oracle identifiers are case-sensitive...

Comment: method is the symbolic name used in the call. It is lowercase in the call and in the ORA-06550 message

Comment: I don´t know how Genexus would make the procedures visible to the account connected to

Answer (score 1):

I found this in the Genexus documentation:

"Stored Functions (Oracle) are not supported; use Stored Procedures with InOut or Out parameters"

So, that is the way to follow